# Access denied for service account when accessing IAP-protected application

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase, google-oauth

Trying to let a python command line to access(HTTP GET) IAP-protected application.

With https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iap/make_iap_request.py

But 403 err occurs Exception: Service account xxx@xxxxxxxxx-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have permission to access the IAP-protected application.

Following methods have been tried, but still issue persists as above
1. remove/create the service account
2. re-create the json key file
3. grant the service account project `owner` permission

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ[
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/Users/foo/bar.json'

    print make_iap_request('https://foo.com/', 'xxxxtheidforthatiapservice.apps.googleusercontent.com')
```

Comment: Did you try adding the service account email address to IAP authorization screen (Info Panel) and assign it an IAP role? I have only tested with User Identies, so I am not sure that service accounts are a supported identity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to follow the [Authenticating from a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) procedure:

> Use an OpenID Connect (OIDC) token to authenticate a service account
>   to a Cloud IAP-secured resource.
>
> 1. Add the service account to the [access list](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access) for the Cloud IAP-secured project.
> 2. Generate a [JWT-based access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth). This uses a `target_audience` additional claim that requires a client ID. To find
>      your client ID, follow the steps below:
>
>    a. Go to the Cloud IAP page.
>
>    b. Find the resource you want to access, then click **More > Edit
>      OAuth Client**.
>
>    `edit OAuth client on the More menu`
>
>    c. On the **Credentials** page that appears, note the client ID.
> 3. Request an [OIDC](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) token for the Cloud IAP-secured client ID.
> 4. Include the OIDC token in an `Authorization: Bearer` header to make the authenticated request to the Cloud IAP-secured resource.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

You have to run the script authenticated as a service account used to access the IAP-protected application programmatically. You can do so either by running script [directly from VM which uses that service account as default](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account), or you will need to download SA credentials and do it locally [Obtaining an OIDC token from a local service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_from_a_local_service_account_key_file)

Besides that, you also need to assign the `IAP-secured Web App User` role to the desired Service Account for that particular IAP-protected app.

[image]

After that, rerun the script.